# C program changing directories

Tags: c, command

Hello I am writing a C program, I am new to it, I use `system` to run commands but whenever I type in `cd..` it shows the correct directory but it always stays there.

```
int main(){

char command[20];

    while(1){
       scanf("%s", &command); //typing in cd..
       //it returns "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Drive\"
       system(command);
    }
}
```

I type in the same again it still seems to be in the same directory. How do I change directories in C using `system`?

Comment: What's with everyone using `system` for everything instead of the proper calls? [`man chdir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chdir.2.html)

Comment: hmm it's interesting, is there not a way to do this with system? I will check the link thank you @spectras

Comment: It's just that `system` is a hack, no serious program should use it like, ever. It spawns one or more external processes, initializes them, makes them parse the command and run it, then waits for OS to clean them up, all of which are heavy operations, while your program can perfectly do the job, swiftly and efficiently by just directly using the actual calls that the program you start ends up doing anyway. Not to mention it's inherently not cross-platform (depends on which commands are available) and might easily misbehave (what if I copy a virus under name `cd.exe` next to your program?)

Comment: In your case, you probably want `SetCurrentDirectory`.

Comment: As for the actual reason what you do does not work, well since it spawns an external process, it is the external process that changes directory, not yours. Yours waits until the external process has started, changed its own current directory, completed and then resumes.

Comment: (by the way, [`SetCurrentDirectory()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365530(v=vs.85).aspx) is the windows pendant of the `chdir()` function I linked, jxh is right, since you're on windows it's the one you probably want :) ).

Comment: Nice, function :) I definitely would make a use of it. Thanks @spectras

Comment: @RubinDack: no, DONT make use of it. If you have to mess around with the calling process's CWD then you are doing things the wrong way. NEVER rely on relative file paths, ALWAYS use absolute paths.

Comment: `system` calls the shell. It is not a programming problem if you run a normal shell command.

Comment: I think you want to pass in "cd ..", not "cd.." The lack of a space likely causes the command to fail.  You can check the return code of system to see if it succeeded.
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html

Answer (score 0):

The Linux system function named 'chdir' you can use in your program . 'chidr' could change the program current directory when program is running.

The program will be a process of the linux when it is running. The system will copy the environment variables to this process. In these environment variables, a variable named PWD remains the current directory path of the process. Thus you can use the following program to show the value of all environment variables:

```
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   extern char **environ;
   int main()
   {
       char **env = environ;
      //show the current directory path
      printf("PWD: %s\n", getenv("PWD"));
      //show all environment variables.
       while(*env)
       {
           printf("%s\n",*env);
           env++;
       }
    return 0;
   }
```

Thus you can change the value of the variable "PWD" by calling the system function named "chdir" and show the current path by calling the system function named "getenv".
In addition, you can show the detail information of environment variables by using the following shell commond:

```
man 7 environ
```

If you don't know how to use the "chdir" function, you can use the following shell common line to get help:

```
man chdir
```